# Differential equation of $\frac{dy}{dx} + y =\sin x, y(0)= 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I am struggling with this differential equation, and I will appreciate some help.
First order differential equation of

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \sin x,\quad
 y(0)= 0 .
$$

Comment: What have you tried? You'll have to show what you've done to get the answer here.

Comment: What kind of function might $y$ be?  Since you have $\sin x$ in the equation, maybe it's another sinusoid ($y = a \cos x + b \sin x + c$)?  Can you work things out from there?

Comment: Solve the homogeneous equation first, then try to find a particular solution like suggested by @Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\sin(x),\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{(1)}
\\
{y(0)=0}.
\\
\frac{dy}{dx}+Py=Q,\implies{P}=1.
$$
We must calculate the **integrating factor**:
$$
e^{\int{Pdx}}=e^{\int{dx}}=e^{x}.
$$
Next we have to multiply the provided equation by the integrating factor:
$$
e^{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{x}y=e^{x}\sin(x).\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{(2)}
$$
If we will see in the left part of the transformed equation $(2)$, we can notice it corresponds to the main formula: $\bbox[lightgreen]{(uv)^{'}=u^{'}v+v^{'}u}$. Therefore, $\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x}y\right)=e^{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{x}y$.

Therefore,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x}y\right)=e^{x}\sin(x),
\\
\int{d}\left(e^{x}y\right)=\int{e^{x}}\sin(x),
$$
Also we know the standard table integral:
$$
\bbox[pink]
{
\int{e^{ax}}\sin(bx)dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^{2}+b^{2}}\left(a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)\right)
}.
$$
In our case the parameters $\bbox[lightblue]{a=1}$ and $\bbox[lightblue]{b=1}$ relatively of the standard table integral.

After that we will have:
$$
ye^{x}=\frac{e^{x}}{2}\left(\sin(x)-\cos(x)\right)+C,
\\
y={0.5}\sin(x)-{0.5}\cos(x)+Ce^{-x}.
$$
From ${y(0)=0}$ we need to determine also:
$$
-0.5+C=0,\implies{C}=0.5,\implies{y}={0.5}\sin(x)-{0.5}\cos(x)+0.5e^{-x}.
$$
Here is the answer:
$$
\bbox[yellow]
{
{y}={0.5}\sin(x)-{0.5}\cos(x)+0.5e^{-x}
}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me!